# how to scan folders in directory and get the folder with the highest number at the end -python

Tags: python, scanning

i am really new to python and i am trying to automate procedure.
i have some folders and i want to enter the folder with the highest number at the end.[in the picture i have some folders. and i want to take the folder with the highest number at the end. for example in this picture, folder_4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkD8q.png)
this is what i tried so far. i do not know how to continue or if my code is any effective.

```py
import os
import shutil
import glob

path="N:\QA\Automation\Projects\AT_Projects"
projectlist = os.listdir(path)
for project in projectlist:
    projectdir = path + "\\" + project
    file_path=[]
    print(projectlist)
 
    if os.path.isdir(projectdir):
        folders=os.listdir(projectdir)
        for folder in folders:
            file_path=folder
        
      
            if os.folderdir.isdir(folder):
            
               print('true')

   
    else:
        print("done")
```

I want to scan the folder and at the end enter folder_4 to get something from it.

how do I do this scan?

Comment: What do you mean with "scan"? You already use `listdir` to get the names of the folders.

Comment: Depends on what exactly you are trying to do. 
You can use `listdir` again, and then `open`, or copy it. you can take a look at `shutil`

Comment: Are the folders recursive? Or just "top level"

Comment: sorry, maybe the word scan is not the right word to describe what i wanted. I meant that it will get all the folder names and output the folder with the highest number at the end

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is in the same folder, you can do something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

p = Path.cwd()  # Alternatively, use Path(<your folder path>) to point to another folder
sorted_folders = list(sorted(p.glob("*[0-9]/"), key=lambda x: int(x.name.split("_")[-1])))
```

This works from the folder containing the folders you want to sort by.

Breaking this down:

1. Using pathlib.Path you get a Path object for the current working directory
2. Use Path.glob with the pattern "*[0-9]/", which gives you a generator for everything in the directory (all your folders) that end with a number
3. Use sorted, with a key that is "split the name on _ an take the last piece of that name", e.g. "folder_1" -> ["folder", "1"]. We apply int so that the last element here is treated as a number, not a string
4. create a list so that you have the folders in order

If you then want the folder with the largest number, you can take the last member of your list

```
sorted_folders[-1]
```

Comment: This will fail if there is a directory that doesn't end in a digit. maybe use `glob("*[0-9]/")` not sure what the syntax is

Comment: nice suggestion! I was taking the assumption that all the folders would follow the number pattern. But, there's no need to make the assumption if you can be more specific about the name pattern